# When will Ubuntu 10.10 be released?

Tags: 10.10

At what time will be Ubuntu 10.10 will be released , in UST or IST ?

Answer (score 15):

The Ubuntu Release team [is committed](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MaverickReleaseSchedule) to releasing 10.10 on Sunday, 10 October, 2010. An actual hour is never given as there are many tests that run, so there's no magic time.

You can find more information in [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1588658).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that's what i heard too. 10/10/2010 at 10:10 GMT. i'm assuming it's AM. I'm in EST (New York) which is -4:00 so I'm hoping it's at around 6:10am for me.

i'm watching the countdown using this: http://www.7is7.com/otto/countdown.html

YAAAAY!

Answer (score 0):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1588658

What time of the day is it going to be released?

It's impossible to tell when precisely it's going to happen. It depends on when the work that needs to be carried out before publishing the images is complete and on when mirrors complete syncing, which in turn depends on network conditions all over the world. Just wait for the announcement.