# What Time Does 10.10 Come Out?

Tags: 10.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will Ubuntu 10.10 be released?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5433/when-will-ubuntu-10-10-be-released)

What time does Ubuntu 10.10 come out
10.10 can't wait!

Answer (score 1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1588658

What time of the day is it going to be released?

It's impossible to tell when precisely it's going to happen. It depends on when the work that needs to be carried out before publishing the images is complete and on when mirrors complete syncing, which in turn depends on network conditions all over the world. Just wait for the announcement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [daily build cds](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily/current/) and apt-get upgrade